# Overloading += for chain operation

Tags: c++, vector, overloading

Let's say I have:

```
class Date {
    int year, month, day;
}
```

and I have `+` operator overloaded:

```
friend CDate operator +(const Date &leftDate, const Date &rightDate) {}
```

where I increment the left date by the right date. That part seems to work.

Now I'd like to overload `+=`, which is trivial if all I'm doing is `date += another_date`.

However, if I have to chain it, for example: `date += another_date + another_date_2` I have to create a vector where `another_date` and `another_date2` would be stored and then do addition for each of them in order:

```
Date& Date::operator +=(const vector<Date> &dates) {
    for(auto date: dates) {
        this->year += date.year;
        this->month += date.month;
        this->day += date.day;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

The part I'm struggling with right now is how do I overload the `+` operator that it returns a vector?

My ideas so far:

- `vector<Date> operator +(const Date &date)`: where would I create a vector? I have to create one in order to insert `date`.
- `vector<Date> operator +(vector<Date> &dates, const Date &date)`: similar problem, I haven't created a vector so far.

So **how do I overload `+` operator that it returns a vector?**

Comment: What is the result of adding March 17, 2018 to April 6, 2017? In other words, you need two **different** types in order for arithmetic to makes sense: one that represents a **date**, such as March 17, 2018, and another that represents a **duration**, such as two years.

Comment: `Date date = (2018, 1, 1); date += Year(3) + Month(3)`, where `Year(3)` would return a `Date` object of `(3, 0, 0)`. I'm sorry I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use

```
date += another_date + another_date_2;
```

it is interpreted as:

```
date += (another_date + another_date_2);
```

I assume that's exactly what you want.

There is no need for a `vector` of objects.

You can also use

```
date += (another_date + another_date_2 + another_date_3 + another_date_4 + ...);
```

Once again, there is no need for a `vector` of objects.

Comment: AFAIK `a += b + c` is `(a += b) += c`, so I need a vector where `b` and `c` would be stored and then do `+` for them in order.

Comment: @LeNguyenDuyAnh, no. `a += b + c` is `a += ( b + c)`. Check out the cppreference.com page on [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: Also `a += b += c` is `a += (b += c)`

Answer (score 0):

Actually you could achieve what you want with monolithic `+` / `+=` - operators taking only `Date` parameters and returning only `Date` objects as shown by Sahu.

If - for any reason probably not motivated by the case shown in your question - you really want the `+`-operator to collect the parameters only and return a vector with them, you could achieve this as follows:

```
class Date {
public:
    int year, month, day;

    Date& operator +=(const vector<Date> &dates) {
        for(auto date: dates) {
            this->year += date.year;
            this->month += date.month;
            this->day += date.day;
        }
        return *this;
    }

};


vector<Date> operator +(const Date &leftDate, const Date &rightDate) {
    vector<Date> result;
    result.push_back(leftDate);
    result.push_back(rightDate);
    return result;
}

vector<Date> operator +(const vector<Date> &left, const Date &rightDate) {
    vector<Date> result = left;
    result.push_back(rightDate);
    return result;
}


int main(void)
{
    // vector<Date> rhs = Date { 2,2,2 } + Date { 3,3,3 } + Date { 4,4,4 };

    Date d = { 1,1,1 };
    d += Date { 2,2,2 } + Date { 3,3,3 } + Date { 4,4,4 };
    return 0;
}
```